# sorting DGV on header click

Tags: c#, mysql, sorting, datagridview

Currently my system is connected via mysql data base to get the data from mysql to dgv.
I need a code that can blend with my current code on sorting the data when clicked on header. Sorry for poor english.

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString; //Set your MySQL connection string here.
        string query = "SELECT lrn,first_name,middle_name,last_name,grade_and_section,student_gender,student_guardian,contact_number FROM student_info;"; // set query to fetch data "Select * from  tabelname"; 
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataStudent.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dataStudent.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "LRN";
                dataStudent.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "First Name";
                dataStudent.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "Middle Name";
                dataStudent.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "Last Name";
                dataStudent.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "Grade And Section";
                dataStudent.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "Gender";
                dataStudent.Columns[6].HeaderCell.Value = "Guardian";
                dataStudent.Columns[7].HeaderCell.Value = "Contact Number";

                dataStudent.Columns[5].Visible = false;
                dataStudent.Columns[6].Visible = false;
                dataStudent.Columns[7].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }


private void dataStudent_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {


        int index = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataStudent.Rows[index];
        txtLRN.Text = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtFName.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtMName.Text = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtLName.Text = selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtYear.Text = selectedRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtGender.Text = selectedRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txtGuardian.Text = selectedRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txtContact.Text = selectedRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: after you populate the data in DGV , you can use the following 
 - foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    { column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic; }

Comment: everytime i clicked on header, this error always shows "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'"

on DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataStudent.Rows[index];

Comment: What is the value of `index` when the error occurs?

Comment: You need to test for index<0 before any other processing in the dataStudent_CellClick.

Comment: and if you are making visible false for certain columns then why include that in dataStudent_CellClick event.